# Why is Rails to_json giving a different result than Ruby to_json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a Ruby script that converts a hash to json and writes it into a file. I use the `to_json` method.

In the file, I get the following result:

`{"name":"Bob","age":42}`

I copied this script in a module within the `lib` directory of my Rails app and now, when I call it from a controller, I get the following result written into the file:

`{"name":"Bob","age":"42"}`

Notice that `42` is now `"42"`. Why is that? How can I force Rails to write it as `42` instead of `"42"`?

This causes me issues because my app is processing the file and when converting it back to a hash, the int is now a string.

**EDIT**

It seems that the `json` gem was not installed. That's strange because both my Ruby script and the Rails version were able to call `to_json`. `gem list` also shown `json 1.8.3` in the list of installed gems. Still, since I ran `gem install json`, everything works as expected. Integers are jsonified as integers.

Can anybody explain why the `to_json` and `require 'json'` in my Ruby script was working even though I couldn't `require 'json'` from irb?

Comment: Of course your question is of interest. But your solution in quite simple. Just test the value for being an Integer or String with is_a? and then convert to the appropriate according to your needs. Then, free from the issue that is breaking your software, all time is available to find the reasons for this strange behavior. Gonna to some tests here myself.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida Yes, I get that the workaround is easy (although I don't have access to the processing part), I would still like to know why my script produces a certain output when executed from the Ruby command line and another when called from a Rails context.

Comment: Sure @ilovebigmacs. This deserves to be studied.

Comment: I don't see this in my Rails 4.1 app; it JSONifies integers as integers. What JSON-related gems do you have in your Gemfile or Gemfile.lock?

Comment: tried that in my rails console and got the correct format `"{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":42}"`

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Interesting... I could call `to_json` in my Rails console and it was giving me a string instead of an integer. I tried the same in irb and it didn't work. Couldn't even `require 'json'`. When typing `gem list` it shows me that I have `json 1.8.3` but still, I ran `gem install json` and it installed it. Now, everything works fine. Both from Rails console and from irb. I still can't understand how my Ruby script could work with `to_json` in it. That's a mystery.

Comment: json is a gem, not in the standard library so it's not loaded by default in IRB. This might be issue with gem versions. When you test `to_json` in different environments, check for differences between the json gem's version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is simply to run `gem install json` even if `gem list` shows that json is already installed.